# How to get total height of scrollY?

Tags: javascript, css

How to get total height of scrollY?

i have tried any object prototype but no one equals to the total of my scrollY when i scroll it.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
  console.log(window.scrollY);
});
```

how to get the window.scrollY total?

Comment: Not even `document.documentElement.scrollTop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look here bro! everything is given step by step with its complete explanation:
https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window